# VS 2017 Database project, triggers are missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created a SQL Server database project and imported my existing database. All looks good except triggers. And when I do a Schema compare, it shows triggers as difference. Am I missing any settings? My database project's database version and target version is same (SQL Server 2016).

For some reason for one of my stored procedure the difference is

[screenshot: stored procedure compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT08x.png)

As I just imported the existing database, I was expecting they should be identical.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093876/why-is-ssdt-schema-compare-showing-difference-in-defaultexpressionscript

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean thanks! Any thoughts on missing triggers?

Comment: Not really, the "DefaultExpressionScript" was a PC Load Letter moment for me, so I had to look it up and that led to that other question.